# How check if SHA512 is enable for TLS1.2 in Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, windows-update

Im trying to apply the KB2973337 but inst installing with the error "the update is not applicable to your computer"..

How can I check if SHA512 is enable for TLS 1.2 on my Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1?
Can't find the KB on my system and i really don't know why inst applicable...

Comment: You need to be very sure that you're downloading the correct package applicable for your OS (Server 2008 R2). Check this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2973337/sha512-is-disabled-in-windows-when-you-use-tls-1-2

Comment: Adding to that, the update KB2973337  has been superseded by the updates kb2992611, kb3042058, kb3125574, and kb3172605. If any of the latter 4 updates are installed in the server, this update will not apply. And, that'd also mean that required patching has been done.